# JavaScript library to render obfuscated images

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I'm designing a website that displays commercial images and want to avoid people saving the image on their computer. I realise that any security measure like this can be defeated by a determined attacker. I'm just looking for approaches the make things harder - enough to deter a casual attacker.

One idea I had was to serve valid images, with the pixel data encrypted, e.g. each byte XORed with X. JavaScript in the page would decrypt this and render the original image in a <canvas> block.

Can anyone recommend a library that helps implement this or a similar scheme?

Comment: Casual attackers can still just simply "print-screen" them.

Comment: @gre_gor - True, I guess that makes this pretty pointless. Gonna leave the question up in case I get any other ideas.

Comment: The canvas also has "Save image as" option on right click.

Comment: @gre_gor - Looks like a dead-end. I may use a Windows native app. Still not foolproof of course.

Comment: Even with a desktop app, no matter how much effort you put into disabling screen capture, there will be a way for the user to overcome it, especially if the user is a local Windows admin. You could consider adding a watermark (either heavy or light) on the displayed images if that doesn't obstruct the applications functionality and usefulness. This way, the users can't re-sell the images as their own.

Comment: @AminDodin - Yeah, good point. I still want to deter casual capture, and I've found a tutorial for that on Windows desktop, although I've not tried it. Images will be invisibly watermarked, but there are tricks to remove watermarks. Nothings foolproof